# insert value from mysql column to certain users

Tags: mysql, session, user-interface, logging, authentication

Is there a user session that for example if

Gabriel has a sales code of 4 and Josh has one of 3

when either of them log in, the number appears as value automatically in a input text field?

Its for a invoice that requires a sales code for each person.

any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you using? Just set the session variable 'sales_code' (queried from the DB) after the user logs in, and display it in the text field when necessary.